# ¿Cómo puedo comparar los valores de variables?

Tags: javascript

Con el siguiente código:

```
var p1 = "Chile";
var p2 = "Colombia";
var p3 = "Perú";
var p4 = "Colombia";
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar la palabra que más se repite (en este caso Colombia) y sus 2 variables?

Comment: para lo que quieres hacer fuera con un conjunto de if(s), pero lo que sugiero es usar una funcion con un arreglo, no tenerlo con varias variables

Comment: realmente quieres mostrar el nombre de las variables `p2`, `p4`?

Comment: Sería bueno que indicaras qué buscaste, qué probaste, etc. Al fin y al cabo, estamos aquí para _ayudar_, no para hacer tu trabajo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te han comentado, para trabajar con listas de datos, mejor usa un array.
Una vez tienes el array solo hace falta recorrerlo buscando el valor deseado. Si solo deseas saber cuantos hay, puedes usar un contador, pero si quieres saber en que posiciones, guarda las posiciones en otro vector, no hace falta el contador ya que ese dato lo sabrás mirando el tamaño de dicho vector.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var datos=["Chile","Colómbia","Perú","Colómbia"];

function buscar(valor,vector){
 var posiciones=[];
 vector.forEach(function(v,i){
  if (v==valor) posiciones.push(i);
 });
 return posiciones;
}
var resultado=buscar("Colómbia",datos);
document.write("Datos: "+datos+"<br>");
document.write("Hay "+resultado.length+" resultados, en las posiciones: "+resultado);
```

Nota: Estoy dando por sentado que la lista no está ordenada, si lo estuviera se podría optimizar el algoritmo usando varios métodos, como dejando de buscar al encontrar un valor mayor.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var datos=["Chile","Colómbia","Perú","Colómbia"].sort();

function buscar(valor,vector){
 var posiciones=[];
 for (let i=0; i<vector.length && vector[i]<=valor; i++)
  if (valor==vector[i]) posiciones.push(i);
 return posiciones;
}
var resultado=buscar("Colómbia",datos);
document.write("Datos: "+datos+"<br>");
document.write("Hay "+resultado.length+" resultados, en las posiciones: "+resultado);
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que este código te podría ayudar.

```
var p1 = "Chile";
var p2 = "Colombia";
var p3 = "Perú";
var p4 = "Colombia";
var pos=0,aux=0,mayor=0;
array = [p1,p2,p3,p4];
for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++){
    aux=0;
    for(k=0;k<=array.length;k++){
        if(array[i]==array[k]){
            aux ++;
        }
        if(aux>mayor){
            mayor = aux;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Te dará la cantidad de veces que se repite y la posición para que sepas cual es.

Comment: no es el mas eficiente pero resuelve el problema

Answer (score 0):

```
var p1 = "Chile";
var p2 = "Colombia";
var p3 = "Perú";
var p4 = "Colombia";
var pos=0,aux=0,mayor=0;
array = [p1,p2,p3,p4];
for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++){
    aux=0;
    for(k=0;k<=array.length;k++){
        aux=(array[i]==array[k])?aux++;
        if(aux>mayor){
            mayor = aux;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}
```